# Populating Field From Other Object

Tags: trigger, class

Hi i am new in salesforce and i want to ask a question about populating field from other object. There are 2 objects AreaFee and Account.

AreaFee contains pdfCode(text),area(text),fee(currency) as a field and account contains both fields too.

**AreaFEE**(pdfCode,area,Fee)
**account**(pdfCode,area,Fee)

I am trying to do populate Fee field from AreaFee object to account object, i have to control if pdfCode and Area same then get Fee to account object.

I mean if PdfCode= 0042 and area= 01  and Fee= 220 in AreaFee Object then get fee to account Object from AreaFee object. I have to do this with trigger so can you help me the logic of class ? which steps i have to do ?

Comment: is there a relationship between these objects ?

Comment: no there is no relationship between them @SamuelDeRycke

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to synchronize record values between records of different objects, or are trying to synchronize picklist values between 2 pickliest fields on 2 separate objects.  Or are you trying to search/query a record in the other object which has the same field values as a current record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this; AreaFee(PdfCode = 100; Area = 10; Fee = 120) this will update Account(PdfCode = 100; Area = 10; Fee = null)

You need to create a after insert/update trigger on AreaFee object. Then you can write something like this to get Accounts that has same pdfcode and area values as AreaFee objects. Then you have to map each AreaFee object to Account object then update Fee field accordingly. Below code should work.

```
//getting inserted/updated areaFee records
AreaFee[] areaFees = Trigger.new;
//pdfCodes and areas are for Account query.
Set<String> pdfCodes = new Set<String>();
Set<String> areas = new Set<String>();
//We are creating a map with a key value of pdfCode + area. So we can get exact values using same info on Account object record.
Map<String, AreaFee> areaFeeMap = new Map<String, AreaFee>();
for(AreaFee af: areaFees){
    pdfCodes.add(af.PdfCode);
    areas.add(af.Area);
    //this creates a key of pdf code and area to AreaFee object
    areaFeeMap.put(af.PdfCode + af.Area, af);
}
List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, PdfCode, Area, Fee FROM Account WHERE PdfCode IN :pdfCodes AND Area IN :areas];

List<Account> toUpdate = new List<Account>();
for(Account a: accounts){
    //if we have Accounts that can create same key values we will update its fee accordingly. if not it will not do anything
    if(areaFeeMap.get(a.PdfCode + a.Area) != null){
        a.Fee = areaFeeMap.get(a.PdfCode + a.Area).Fee;
        toUpdate.add(a);
    }
}

update toUpdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as trigger is concerned it can easily be made but in your case the condition is ambiguous as you want to get  Fee to account object if pdfCode and Area same in the AreaFee object but the example that you have provided does not have both fields equal so can you clerify the condition so that i can help you on the trigger.

Comment: I keep pdfCode,area and Fee records in AreaFee object. and with zipcode i retrieve area field from another object to account. and i have no relation between AreaFEE and Account. So when pdfCode and area inserted to account then it has to populate fee from AreaFee object to Account's Fee field.